# Why do I get "security.Groups: Group mapping impl=org.apache.hadoop.security.ShellBasedUnixGroupsMapping; cacheTimeout=300000"?

Tags: hadoop, nutch, hdfs

```
$hdfs dfs -rmr crawl
    11/04/16 08:49:33 INFO security.Groups: Group mapping impl=org.apache.hadoop.security.ShellBasedUnixGroupsMapping; cacheTimeout=300000
```

I'm using hadoop-0.21.0 with the [default Single Node Setup configuration](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/single_node_setup.html#Local).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a warning, just a standard message.  It shouldn't have been output at INFO level, however, because it does get printed with every message.  In trunk it has been moved to DEBUG so you don't normally see it ([in this JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-6763)).  This will be incorporated into the next release.

Answer (score 0):

It's just an INFO what's your problem?

Comment: @Thomas - It gets printed at every hdfs command and I suspect it's meant to signal a problem.

Comment: do you login with the passwordless ssh user before you executed the command?

Comment: @Thomas - I don't login..I'm in the Single Node Setup config

Comment: you'll must have a passwordless ssh user in order to run these setups. follow this: http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/#configuring-ssh

Comment: @Thomas - what setups? Where is this officialy documented?

Comment: @Thomas - but why should I run in Pseudo-Distributed Operation, as you point to? I'm running in Standalone Operation.